# Similar JQuery selectors acting differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have a page with 10 divs which contain the class "topic_t".  The code below:

```
console.log(jQuery(".topic_t").length);
console.log(jQuery('*[class="topic_t"]').length);
```

produces result:

```
10
0
```

```js
console.log(jQuery(".topic_t").length);
console.log(jQuery('*[class="topic_t"]').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="apple baker charly topic_a topic_t"></div>
<div class="apple baker charly topic_a topic_t"></div>
<div class="apple baker charly topic_a topic_t"></div>
<div class="apple baker charly topic_a topic_t"></div>
<div class="apple baker charly topic_a topic_t"></div>
<div class="apple baker charly topic_a topic_t"></div>
<div class="apple baker charly topic_a topic_t"></div>
<div class="apple baker charly topic_a topic_t"></div>
<div class="apple baker charly topic_a topic_t"></div>
<div class="apple baker charly topic_a topic_t"></div>
```

Why does the second jquery selector not find any of the divs?  For example my divs are defined like:

```
<div class="apple baker charly topic_a topic_t">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `[attributeName="attributeValue"]` will select elements which have an `attributeName` of exactly `attributeValue`.

`*[class="topic_t"]` will select any element whose class attribute is *exactly* `topic_t`. In contrast, when you use `.` syntax to select a class, that will select any element which has that class substring *inside the space-separated list* of classes (in the `class` attribute).

So, using `.` to select elements with a particular class is generally more reliable (and shorter), especially if other classes might exist too.

Answer (score 1):

Because `class="topic_t"` means select any elements with the class attribute equal to `"topic_t"`. It doesn't mean select any elements with the class attribute which *includes* the class `"topic_t"`:

For example, the following works as your div's class attribute is set to `"topic_t"`:

```js
console.log(jQuery('*[class="topic_t"]').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topic_t"></div>
```

If you use the contains selector (`~=`) instead it will work as expected (which behaves similarly to the `.class` selector):

```js
console.log(jQuery('*[class~="topic_t"]').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="apple baker charly topic_a topic_t"></div>
```